# Ubuntu PPC Powerbook g4 wont boot live cd

Tags: ppc

I have a 867mhz Powerbook g4 ti. It has 1 gig of ram. I can not get it to boot any live cd for ppc architecture. I have even tried other distro's for ppc. All always do the same thing. They start to boot. Then get to a weird washed out looking screen. Tried `video=ofonly` and tried a few other commands specific to my video card I found others had luck with. Just want to get hardy heron running on this machine.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure your computer has a Broadcom b43 Wifi card, which isn't compatible with some livecds.  Try the 11.10 cd and use the b43-fwcutter.  I have a pc with a b43 and this is how I got Ubuntu to work.  You can also try pressing esc wen you get to the splash screen.  You can see if it stops for any errors.