# Missing firmware error on Lubuntu 12.04 LiveCD: b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode5.fw" not found

Tags: boot, drivers, lubuntu, internet, broadcom

I'm trying to install Lubuntu 12.04 LTS on my iBook G4 as the OS X 10.4.11 really isn't all that great. I originally tried to use the minimal CD, but that failed as you can see by my question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/396885/choose-a-mirror-of-the-ubuntu-archive-on-lubuntu-13-10-minimal-install. I think that issue may be caused by this same issue, as there I believe there is no actual internet connection.

So, I decided to try the full 12.04 CD, but I am now getting an error during the boot:

```
...stuff here (logo and other boot messages - all unrelated)
*starting configure network device
[ 110.081458] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43/ucode5.fw" not found
[ 110.081669] b43-phy0 ERROR: Firmware file "b43-open/ucode5.fw" not found
[ 110.081870] b43-phy0 ERROR: You must go to http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/b43#devicefirmware
and download the correct firmware for driver version. Please carefully read all
instructions on the website.
```

This is most perturbing. This [post](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2136439) says that 10.04 works fine, but since 10.04 is EOL, I don't want to install it. This [question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223158/ubuntu-ppc-powerbook-g4-wont-boot-live-cd) suggests using the LiveCD with b43-fwcutter driver and trying to push <kbd>ESC</kbd> during the boot to see any errors. Also, would pushing <kbd>Shift</kbd> during the boot help any?

 I probably will have to blacklist the b43 driver, but I'm not sure how.

There is a bug regarding this here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/956677 and the suggested solution *is* blacklisting the driver in the kernel param string, but again, I have no clue how to change the param string. I'm going to research blacklisting a little more, but since I am using the CD, I can't download/install drivers, like I could on USB (my iBook refuses to boot USB, even with Open Firmware hacking.) **EDIT**: I have looked around for blacklisting

This blog post: http://clusterbleep.net/blog/2012/05/09/ubuntu-12-04-splash-screen-lockup-with-livecd/ is exactly my issue, but I never get a Install/Disk Options screen. Would holding <kbd>Shift</kbd> during the boot allow me to get to this? I have to hold <kbd>C</kbd> and then enter `live` to start the LiveCD and then I would hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>.

How do I fix this issue? The system is a July 2005 iBook G4 1.33GHz PPC/512MB RAM/40GB HDD/unsure what graphics card/and as can be seen from this issue probably a Broadcom B43 internet chip thingy.

Comment: Can I ask a question about both of the correct answers? How do I get to a prompt to that will allow me to run the command "sudo b43-fwcutter /lib..."? And , where do I download the firmware from? Thank you in advance and I am sorry if this is not the proper procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved this on my own, so I'm creating a self-answer.

I downloaded the firmware manually on another PC and then ran the command `sudo b43-fwcutter /lib/firmware FIRMWARE/FILE/LOCATION/HERE/wl_prebuilt.o`

Then I restarted and it works!

Answer (score 3):

### Installation Instructions for Broadcom network devices

First you will have to identify your chip ID as each one is supported by more than one driver/module.

Run this command to know your network chip details ('14e4' to find only broadcom devices)

```
lspci -vvnn | grep 14e4
```

It will display something like this:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4322 802.11a/b/g/n Wireless LAN Controller [14e4:432b] (rev 01)
```

Now here,

The Chip ID is BCM4322

The PCI-ID is [14e4:432b]

Your chip id will be different. Now when you know your chip-id, find the driver supporting your network chip from this official ubuntu page:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/Driver/bcm43xx#b43%20-%20Internet%20access

The page has installation instructions for each driver as well.

Don't forget to reboot your system after driver inslalation.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 2):

With a wired connection, install the firmware package:

```
sudo apt-get install linux-firmware-nonfree
```

Now the b43 driver should work.  If you started blacklisting things, undo all that, nothing else is needed.

Answer (score 1):

This is the terminal command that works for me.

sudo apt-get install firmware-b43-installer

-many blessings