# Cannot run Ubuntu 12.04.4 live or install Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04

I have had exposure to Linux in the past (principally Mandrake and Knoppix), and have experimented with various live Linux distributions.

My mother's laptop runs Windows XP, and has recently been riddled with malware. I have successfully run Live distributions of Knoppix 7.2.00 & Ubuntu 12.04 on it earlier this year. However following the malware (most of which has been removed) I cannot run Ubuntu 12.04.41 live (or any other live distributions) or install Ubuntu 12.04.41 on the C drive (there is 50 GB free).

When Ubuntu boots from the DVD, the program gets as far as asking whether to install/run from DVD, then goes to a purple screen with Ubuntu 12.04, with several flashing dots below it. After a while a series of error messages appear commencing with an error message B43/VCODES.FW, with a link to the relevant website. I have downloaded/run the drivers mentioned, but nothing changes.

I have tried loading Ubuntu 12.04 on a flash drive using Pendrive Linux, but despite the BIOS settings being set to boot from USB then DVD then C drive, the results are identical to the DVD.

I really don't know how to proceed. I cannot erase XP & Picasa until Ubuntu (or another distribution) works and there seems to be no point in replacing the built-in (scsi) drive until it does. I have run out of ideas. All suggestions will be gratefully received.

Comment: Please could you post the exact error messages. From what I Googled, B43/VCODES.FW sounds like a driver problem with your wifi adapter.  Lastly, I would recommend that you try a newer version of Ubuntu, or Xubuntu if you do no want unity.  Driver support will be much better on the new versions.

Answer (score 2):

Could you try Ubuntu 14.04?  The B43 error you mention is a wifi error and could be solved by [missing firmware](https://askubuntu.com/questions/404503/missing-firmware-error-on-lubuntu-12-04-livecd-b43-phy0-error-firmware-file-b).  I think it should be fixed in 14.04.

Also, maybe your Mother's laptop has a rootkit, have you scanned for those?